# Check whether terminal was created from profile in VS Code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VS Code extension where custom terminals are created both programmatically through the `createTerminal()` API and by the user through a contributed terminal profile.

Is there a way to check if a terminal was created by the user from the profile?
(I plan to use the check while listening for `onDidOpenTerminal()`).